# Composition of continious and analytic map

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

> Let $U,V,W\subset\mathbb{C}$ open and connected, $f:U\to V$ continous and $g:V\to W$ analytic and non-constant. If $g\circ f$ is analytic, does then $f$ have to be analytic as well?

I guess the answer is yes but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**.

For convenience let us denote $h=g\circ f$. If $f$ is a constant function, there is nothing to prove. In below we will assume that $f$ is non-constant. Then $f(U)$ is a connected set containing more than one point, and hence it contains some accumulation point. Since $g$ is analytic and non-constant, by [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), $h(U)=g(f(U))$ contains more than one point, so $h$ is non-constant.

To show that $f$ is analytic on $U$, it suffices to show that for any $z_0\in U$, $f$ is analytic on some open neighborhood of $z_0$. There are two cases to discuss.

(i) If $g'(f(z_0))\ne 0$, then by [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Holomorphic_Functions), there exists an open neighborhood $V_0$ of $f(z_0)$ contained in $V$, such that $g|_{V_0}$ has an analytic inverse. As a result, on $f^{-1}(V_0)$ we have $f=(g|_{V_0})^{-1}\circ h$, so $f$ is analytic on $f^{-1}(V_0)\ni z_0$.

(ii) If $g'(f(z_0))=0$, then we claim that there exists an open neighborhood $U_0$ of $z_0$ contained in $U$, such that $g'(f(z))\ne 0$ for every $z\in U_0\setminus\{z_0\}$. Once the claim is proved, from the discussion in case (i) we know that $f$ is analytic on $U_0\setminus\{z_0\}$. Since $f$ is continuous at $z_0$, by [Riemann's removable singularity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem), $f$ is analytic on $U_0$.

Now we are only left to prove the claim. Suppose the claim is not true, so there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}\subset U\setminus\{z_0\}$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}z_n=z_0$, such that $g'(f(z_n))=0$ for every $n$. On the one hand, since $g$ is non-constant, $g'$ is not constantly $0$; on the other hand, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(z_n)=f(z_0)$. Then by [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), $f(z_n)=f(z_0)$ when $n$ is large. However, it follows that $h(z_n)=h(z_0)$ when $n$ is large, and by identity theorem again, $h$ must be constant.  This contradiction completes the proof.

Comment: Looks very good, thank you! Could you explain a little bit more how you conclude by the identity theorem that $f(z_n)=f(z_0)$?

Comment: @Julian: You are welcome. Since $g'(f(z_n))=0$ for every $n$ and since $g'$ is not constantly $0$, by identity theorem the set $\{f(z_n)\}$ cannot have accumulation point in $V$. However, we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(z_n)=f(z_0)$, so the only possible case is $f(z_n)=f(z_0)$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Comment: @Julian: Sorry, I misread a condition in your question when posting my answer. I assumed $g\circ f$ being non-constant instead of $g$ being non-constant in earlier version of my answer. Now it is corrected.