# Showing a function analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $U$ be an open connected subset in $\mathbb C$ and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a continuous map such that the map $z\mapsto (f(z))^n$ is analytic. Show that $f(z)$ is analytic.
Now if we take $g(z)=(f(z))^n$ then $g$ is analytic. Then derivative of $g$ of any order is also analytic. But I am not sure whether it will help in proving analyticity of $f$. Another thought that I am having is since $f$ is given to be continuous we may use Morera'st theorem. Any help?

Comment: No.The $n-$th derivative is not $n! f(z)$.

Comment: Yes sir. Silly mistake.

Comment: See a more general result here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556080/composition-of-continious-and-analytic-map